# How to check healtiness/liveness of a single war deployed in wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, admin, health-monitoring, wildfly-22

I am using a Wildfly 22 server and I want to check liveness/healtiness of a single deployed war application: is it possible? In the [administration guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Admin_Guide.html#Health) I've only found generic endpoints, and I've not found any example on the web. Thank you.